Cannot change date format in gnuplot
I want to adjust the x axis format whilst using a csv file to load my data. The script below does not work with the associated data.
min_example.csv
12-03 17:40:54,6
12-03 18:40:54,5
12-03 19:40:54,9

set datafile separator ","
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d-%m %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%d %H"
plot 'min_example.csv' using 1:2:xtic(1)

The output is still in the "%d-%m %H:%M:%S" format.
Many thanks!
When using a dataset with more data (e.g., 12/4) it still sorts correctly by date and time, but I can't modify anything else. The xtics are an explicit list. I already checked that the "space" character is not a \t; it is definietly a space.

Your script has bypassed normal formatting of the x-axis tic labels by using the command plot ... using 1:2:xtic(1).   The xtic(1) part tells it to use the content (i.e. the character string) in column 1 as the tic label.
You need to apply the new format to the time value represented by the string in column 1, not to the character string itself.  The time value represent by the string in column 1 can be accessed as timecolumn(1). Let's define a function to apply the new format to a time value:
reformat(time) = strftime("%d %H", time)

and now rewrite the script to use that function in plotting
$DATA << EOF
12-03 17:40:54,6
12-03 18:40:54,5
12-03 19:40:54,9
EOF

set datafile separator ","
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d-%m %H:%M:%S"
reformat(time) = strftime("%d %H", time)
plot '$DATA' using 1:2:xtic(reformat(timecolumn(1)))



Many thanks, that solves it! Do you happen to have documentation on the formatting of "plot ... using"? I aim to tweak plotstyles but the documentation of specifics is spread across many manuals and examples. For instance, I want to modify the frequency of x-ticks using time syntax, but the docs don't apply to the 'plot ... using' syntax. Thanks!

My follow-up was answered by this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350929/11562331, I just need to combine both answers.
